# How to check if a reference error is defined?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create combinations in Google Sheets through a script but whenever I try to run my script I get Reference Error: "print" is not defined.

```
function printCombinations(array, k){
    var combinations = [];


    function run(level, start){

        for(var i=start; i < array.length - k + level + 1; i++){
            combinations[level] = array[i];

            if(level < k - 1){
                run(level + 1, i + 1);
            } else {
                print(combinations.join(" "));
            }
        }

    }


    run(0, 0);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this error occurs and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: `print` is not defined. What do you want to do here `print(combinations.join(" "));`? Whatever it is, `print` is not defined anywhere. Get it? It doesn't know what you mean by `print(whatever)`

Comment: I'm trying to return the array into k number of cells.

Comment: There is no "print" command" in Google Apps Script. Client side - you can use console.log() or on the server side Logger.log() with your variable inside the brackets

Answer (score 2):

**Appending to a Spreadsheet**

There is no print command in Google Apps Script.  There is a [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) that you can use clientside in Javascript and it works on most desktops and laptops and some mobiles. But that's for printing to a printer. If you just want to output a string to a spreadsheet then this sort of thing might suffice for your needs.

```
function print(string) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.appendRow([string]);
}
```

[Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Animation:
[image]